# Ajax File upload. sending formData

Tags: ajax, file-upload, nodes, multipartform-data

**HTML**

```
<form id="uploadimage" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="file-input btn btn-block btn-primary">
            + add files
            <input type="file" name="files" id="image_upload" >
        </div>
    </form>
```

**JS**

```
$('#image_upload').change(function(){
var formdata = $(this).parent().parent();
$.ajax({
     url: "/server.php", // Url to which the request is send
     type: "POST",             // Type of request to be send, called as method
     data: new FormData(formdata), // Data sent to server, a set of key/value pairs (i.e. form fields and values)
     contentType: false,       // The content type used when sending data to the server.
     cache: false,             // To unable request pages to be cached
     processData:false,        // To send DOMDocument or non processed data file it is set to false
     success: function(data)   // A function to be called if request succeeds
     {
         alert(data);                          
     }
 });
```

**Server.php**

```
if(isset($_FILES["file"]["type"]))
        {
            echo "YES";
        }
        else echo "NO";
```

I've tryied to do different things but continue to get **NO** as answer.
Any way to receive positive answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing a jQuery object to your FromData constructor, which takes a form.
Expose the form from the jQuery object when you pass it

```
data: new FormData(formdata[0]), // Data sent to server, a set of key/value pairs (i.e. form fields and values)
```